# LINQ to SQL table class performance

Tags: c#, performance, linq-to-sql

I can't find the performance characteristics for System.Data.Linq.Table<T entity> methods! I refer to methods like insertonSubmit and deleteonSubmit. Are these methods are O(1) or O(n)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `InsertOnSubmit` and `DeleteOnSubmit` take a single object, so their performance should be `O(1)`: all they do is appending to the insertion queue, which is either an `O(1)` or an amortized `O(1)` for all unordered containers.

`InsertAllOnSubmit` and `DeleteAllOnSubmit`, on the other hand, are `O(N)`, where `N` is the length of the `IEnumerable` passed into the method.

Comment: It was just what I wanted to know. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean O(n) in terms of the size of the underlying table, and you're talking about once they get submitted, not just calling the function (which is O(1) as mentioned). I haven't seen any of the implementation of LINQ, but just from the experience with it and my understanding of SQL, the insert method should be O(n) in terms of the existing table, and O(n) in terms of how many submissions there are.

Since the whole thing is submitted at once, I'm assuming it's a transaction, or union of the insert statements, meaning only the first insert suffers the O(n), and the rest of them are just O(1).

I don't think there's a way to make a delete statement happen quicker than O(n), so I'm assuming that's how long it takes.

Of course, since LINQ just translates to SQL and leaves the actual implementation to the database server, a lot of this is up to the database server.

Comment: Main point is the last - whatever the SQL takes, have fun trying to be faster even with handwritten SQL. In many cases it just does not work.